# Internal Server Error on PHP files

Tags: php, postgresql, debian

I've configured PHP5, Apache2 in a debian machine. And the PostgreSQL server is in a different machine. ODBC connection is successful when i use this command in the terminal **isql -v [database name]** and i even can execute the queries successfully. But the challenge is when I open the PHP files through Chrome i'm getting the error like the one in the snapshot below [Web Console].[image]

I've configured the ODBC in my local Windows Machine and I can see the result of the same PHP file when executed through my Local WAMP Server but i get the error when i try to open it through the Linux machine.

Somebody please help me on this.

Comment: You'll have to look at the error log on your server and provide us with the information from there.

Comment: go to `/var/log/apache2` and check your `error.log` file

Comment: Out of curiosity - why do you use ODBC?

Answer (score 1):

How is your PHP configured? suPHP, FastCGI, CGI or DSO? You should also be able to take a look at the error logs for Apache:

`tail -n 200 /usr/local/apache/logs/error_log`

That will list the last 200 lines. You need to be looking for the 500 error. I suspect it's due to permissions, so you may also want to check out the `suexec` log:

`tail -n 200 /usr/local/apache/logs/suexec_log`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. PHP was uninstalled without my knowledge and that was the reason for the error. Installed it again and everything's running as smooth as butter.